# How to let the recruiter know I'm attending graduate school after summer internship?

Tags: resume, internship

I'm currently a rising senior student in the U.S., and I'm starting my application for fall 2018 MSCS programs this September. Meanwhile, I'm seeking a CS internship for summer 2018.

I know normally recruiters will only hire someone who's returning to school later on for an intern position, so they usually hire a rising junior or senior. But in my case I'm returning to school as well (even though I have not started my application yet but I'm confident in getting admitted by some programs), how should I mention my plan in my resume so that recruiters will consider me for intern positions?

Comment: Aren't you writing cover letters? The right place to mention this would be there. Or are you concerned about being dropped from consideration by an automatic system or someone not bothering to read the letter?

Comment: Lilienthal, I'm not planning to write a cover letter and the reason is same as what you mentioned.

Comment: Are you applying at job fairs or through your school? Because if you're contact employers directly they typically expect a cover letter. Note that your cover letter can be the email you sent with your resume attached, it's not always an actual separate letter.

Comment: I'm most likely applying through some companies' online application systems.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the resume is the appropriate place to discuss plans that are not yet firm. Without a specific school and a specific date, it's just a waste of valuable space on your page.

As soon as you know the school and the start date of your program, you can include it in the Education section of your resume with an expected graduation date.

The better place for discussion of your future (undetermined) plans would be in the cover letter.

> I am applying to graduate schools for Fall 2017 and am interested in summer internship work before then.

Comment: Thanks Kent, but I'm not planning to write a cover letter cuz I'm worrying about it not being read. Right now I put an objective section on the top of my resume and wrote "seeking a summer 2018 internship (planning to attend a CS master program in fall 2018)". What do you think of this?